# xaringan code output same style as bookdown

Tags: r, xaringan

Is it possible to customize xaringan to have the code output bookdown style, that is, code and output in the same block?. For instance, see this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 3.1.0.9000     ✔ purrr   0.2.5     
#> ✔ tibble  2.0.0          ✔ dplyr   0.7.8     
#> ✔ tidyr   0.8.2          ✔ stringr 1.3.1     
#> ✔ readr   1.3.1          ✔ forcats 0.3.0
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

The default style has the code and the output in two different blocks:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the **knitr** chunk option](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results) `collapse = TRUE`. For example:

````
```{r, collapse=TRUE}
library(tidyverse)
```
````